# Which column type should I use for storing HTML of an unknown size?

Tags: html, database, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008

What column type should I use for storing html content from a website with an unknown size?

(I'm scanning certain html pages, and create an database entry if there are changes between the last stored entry and the current html code.)

My database is a MSSQL 2008 express database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use varchar(max)

Comment: +1. Or potentially `nvarchar(max)` if you are worried about Unicode chars. It may also be worth noting that `text` has been deprecated in favour of this :)

Comment: you can also use a text column, but varchar(max) is soooo much easy, you can use all the string functions directly on a varchar(max) field...

Comment: @Amadiere: thanx - I forgot nvarchar(max)